# Why this @Transactional method don't do several saves

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional

I am trying to save in same user_friend db table this relationship of friends, but only is persist in db one when method is ended.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public boolean saveLocalFriends(UserFriend userFriend) {

    UserFriend userFriendToRevert = userFriend;

    if (this.friendDao.saveFriend(userFriend)) {

        userFriendToRevert.revert();
        return this.friendDao.saveFriend(userFriendToRevert);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The good way to do this based in @macias contribution.

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public boolean saveLocalFriends(UserFriend userFriend) {

    UserFriend userFriendToRevert = new UserFriend();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(userFriend, userFriendToRevert);    

    if (this.friendDao.saveFriend(userFriend)) {

        userFriendToRevert.revert();

        return this.friendDao.saveFriend(userFriendToRevert);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method posted by you, the single entity is saved twice. I'm not sure what the *revert* method does, but I assume it just changes the state of UserFriend in some way. The second save will basically overwrite the first one. Note that

```
UserFriend userFriendToRevert = userFriend;
```

copies just the reference. If your intention was to persist a modified copy of userFriend you need to do it hard way - construct a new UserFriend object and copy properties one by one, then persist the copy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was assuming each call to save method in DAO was persisting the object independently.